# Placing anylogic agents from excel coordinates

Tags: java, excel, anylogic

I am working with `anylogic` and have some data in an Excel sheet, I have the names of the different agents I want to place in the environment and the `X` and `Y` coordinates.

My problem is that I don't know how to create this agents in the places they are supposed to go, `anylogic` should read the data from the columns `x` and `y` and place the agents in the corresponding destination.

I also don't know why it is happening because my coordinates are referenced to the lower right corner and I believe it is not the same origin that `anylogic` uses. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to import Excel file in built-in database and initialize population with data from the table. In the parameter mapping table, specify `Location X` value as the respective column of the table.

[This how-to video](https://youtu.be/UKCd6BFwdlg?list=PLUJJN9tmVTj1czFMt9IKi6wge9GnmMTN3) demonstrates it with GIS space. Procedure for continuous space is the same.